# Importing table from pdf to excel - Need to uncomment and comment a piece of code for it to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have this almost figured out and it works great, except I run into the following errors anytime I open the workbook and have to go through this process of uncommenting and commenting a section of code.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub ActivateExcel()

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

    'Import_PDF receives the table from the PDF file.
    Sheets("ImportPDF").Select

    'clear all previous data (at the moment this causes an error so look for another way)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ImportPDF").Cells.ClearContents

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


 'IMPORTANT NOTE__________________________________________________________________
 '
 'The section which requires tinkering: this next code below will separate the pdf
 'table into excel columns, however it only needs to be done the first time, and then
 'just pasting works! doing this the 2nd time makes an error. 2nd run now only need to
 'sort a-z the new ImportPDF sheet (put 3.5 after 3 instead of at the end!

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'     Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
'       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
'       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
'       :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
'       Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
'       ), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportPDF").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportPDF").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportPDF").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A3:N26")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    'copy the column from Import_PDF "dev" to the volute sheet which was active on ctrl-b
    '
    Range("B3:B26").Select
    Selection.Copy
    'ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst

    'here select the target active sheet when ctrl-b started the macro:
    'whichever sheet is open during ctrl-b will get the PDF "dev" col now...
    'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & "  activating this sheet now..."
    Sheets(ActiveSheetImport).Select
    'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24

  'need a time delay right here!
  'MsgBox "currently active = " & ActiveSheet.Name & "       active on ctrl-b was = " & ActiveSheetImport

    'and here we can paste to the active cell when ctrl-b started macro:
    'the range is the active cell! that's where the dev col pastes to next line:
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Range("A1").Select
'Range("A1").Activate
'SendKeys ("^v")

'Shell "pskill " & StartAdobe
'Call Shell("TaskKill /F /PID " & CStr(vPID), vbHide)
End Sub
```

So when I first run the macro to import the data into the "ImportPDF" worksheet the data looks like ths:[Error 1][1]

So to solve this: This section of code was written:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
       :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
       Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
       ), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

So I would uncomment this line of code and then re run the macro. I have to run the macro twice. The second time I run the macro I get this error: [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1MpP.jpg)

Once I get that error, if I comment that code again, and run the macro. The data transfer is perfect and works like a charm. But if I close the workbook, I have to redo the entire process. Does anyone know why that is? or how I can fix this issue?

[Error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x9z2.jpg)

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: you can only run TextToColumns on a single column of data: if your `Selection` has multiple columns then it will fail.  Maybe try `Selection.Columns(1).TextToColumns` if it's the forst column you want to operate on.

Comment: I want to operate on the second coloumn. I understand what you mean, but once I comment the code, it works perfectly fine, why is that? Btw, I have just recently started coding on VBA I am a rookie.

Comment: Also the issue is when its importing the data, into the "ImportPDF" worksheet, it doenst copy the table properly and bunches up it all into one coloumn.

Comment: rewrite your code so that you do not use `Select ... Selection`. .... refer to objects directly.   **do not use:** `select range .... selection.texttocolumns`.  **do use:**  `range.texttocolumns`

Comment: Im sorry, I am new to excel. I do not understand what you mean. Are you refering to the entire code? or just the portion I uncomment or comment out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've run TextToColumns once, Excel sometimes "remembers" the settings and automatically applies it to any subsequent paste operation.

One way around this might be to check the Selection.Columns.Count after pasting, then only run the Text to columns if the count is 1

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    If .Columns.Count = 1 Then
        'EDITED
        .TextToColumns Destination:= .Cells(1).Offset(0,1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
           Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
            Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), _
            Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End If
End With
```

Comment: That worked!!!! Thank you. So how it works now is when I first run the macro it will give me an error "Destination reference is not valid" but if I run the macro after it works perfectly fine. Would there be a solution to get rid of error? Once again I really apprecaite the help!

Comment: A1:A28 is the range thats selected

Comment: Tim, so that got rid of the error, but made the data populate all weird. If you see the updated question "error 3" thats how it looks like. The data will import correctly if I run the macro again.

Comment: It's difficult for me to make suggestions without being able to test...